# DocuSign for Salesforce: Recipient Sorting

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I have a custom button that explicitly needs to sort a hard coded recipient with a specific DocuSign role and Sort Order and at the same time load in all contact roles from the related opportunity.

The code below brings in all contact roles (good) but the role of the 'Any Recipient' (which is not a (Salesforce contact role) is defined as 'Customer' (bad) when it should be defined as 'Legal'.

In the (Salesforce) DocuSign Admin | Envelopes settings the roles are defined as 'Customer' and 'Legal' where customer is the first entry and legal is the second.  It appears that the sorting of the recipients is based on the the first entry in DocuSign roles because when I make the first entry 'Legal' and second entry 'Customer' I get the anticipated results.

```
CRL='Email~frasuy@email.com;FirstName~Any;LastName~Signer;Role~Signer 2;RoutingOrder~2,LoadDefaultContacts~1';
```

When using the code below with the DocuSign role entries of Customer (1st) and Legal (2nd) the mappings are working but none of the contact roles are added (bad) as recipients just the entry defined in CRL (good) with the correct DocuSign role - Legal. The LoadDefaultContacts~1 is not respected since none are brought in as recipients.

`CRL='Email~frasuy@email.com;FirstName~Any;LastName~Signer;Role~Signer 2;RoutingOrder~2,LoadDefaultContacts~1'; 
CCRM='Signer 1~Customer;Signer 2~Legal';

CCTM='Signer 1~Signer;Signer 2~Signer';`

How do I bring in all contact roles but explicitly define the DocuSign role for the CRL recipient?

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind the CCRM parameter is used to map a Salesforce role to a DocuSign Role. In this scenario, a "ContactRole to DocuSign Template Role".

Your current button logic is saying "Only pull contacts with the contact role of Signer 1 and Signer 2".

CCRM is typically irrelevant if you're not using DocuSign Server Templates. To answer your question:

**1.** You would need to reference all the **Contact Roles** within CCRM
    and CCTM

**2.** All DocuSign roles must be different because you can't merge two
        contacts with the same role

My example below references all the Salesforce default contact roles:

```
CES='Stackoverflow Example';

CRL='FirstName~Any;LastName~Signer;Email~{!URLENCODE("frasuy@email.com")};RoutingOrder~2;Role~Signer 2,LoadDefaultContacts~1';

CCRM='Decision Maker~Customer;Signer 2~Legal;Business User~Customer2;Economic Buyer~Customer3;Economic Decision Maker~Customer4;Evaluator~Customer5;Executive Sponsor~Customer6;Influencer~Customer7;Technical Buyer~Customer8;Other~Customer9';

CCTM='Decision Maker~Signer;Signer 2~Signer;Business User~Signer;Economic Buyer~Signer;Economic Decision Maker~Signer;Evaluator~Signer;Executive Sponsor~Signer;Influencer~Signer;Technical Buyer~Signer;Other~Signer';
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Using your example, I would be looking to have 3 recipients: 2 from the contact roles + the CRL recipient. Example2: If oppty has contact roles count of 10 then the expected recipient list would be 10 + 1 CRL recipient.  (The user will be manually deleting the (9) recipient rows that are not needed and making the adjustments that would net two rows.)  The CRL recipient would always be a routing order of 2 with a DS role of Legal.  How do I bring in all contact roles as recipients to the envelope + the CRL recipient.

Comment: Are you utilizing templates? If not, you wouldn't need to define CCRM or CCTM and all recipients would merge into the envelope.

Comment: In Example 2, what is the use case for adding 10 + 1 recipients, then to remove 9 of them after?

Comment: We are not using templates but instead custom anchor tags that are included in a pdf that is produced upstream. DSFS is used to send the .pdf.

Comment: RE: Example2. It's really n Contact Roles + 1 CRL recipient (which would never be a contact role.)  We bring in all (n) contact roles + the 1 CRL recipient and the user deletes all contact roles but one. What remains would be two recipients: 1 contact role recipient and the 1 CRL recipient.

Comment: CCRM is designed to reference DocuSign template roles. If you removed this parameter, it would merge all the contacts and would inherit the Recipient Type of "Signer" with routing order 1. If referencing a template role is a preference, you would be required to reference all the default Salesforce Contact Roles within CCRM. I'll edit my previous answer to show my custom button logic.

Comment: How do you handle the situation where multiple contacts have the same role? In your example if both 'good kid' and 'bad kid' have a role of Business User than the mapping drops one of the recipients and would result in 2 recipients when there really should be 3.

Comment: You can't have two contacts with the same role.

Comment: Can a custom DSFS button not be used in this use case, then? Load full contact roles list (contact list could have contacts with the same role) + 1 CRL that map to the appropriate DS role.